# Magento2 multistore - redirect url without store code to default storeView url

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, url, store-code

Not sure if this is a bug in this project, or a Magento2 bug itself

The question is site is configured to **use store code in urls**, and that's working fine... but urls without any store code are loading too, causing SEO problems due to content duplicity

> **Example**: "en" is the store code of default storeView
>
> http://ourproject.com/home -> loads fine
>
> http://ourproject.com/en/home -> loads fine
>
> http://ourproject.com/home should redirect 301 to http://ourproject.com/en/home

Any ideas about how to force (in a clean way) any url to use store code of default storeView?

**update**

We use Apache as webserver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We finally solved this with a light module, using **controller_action_predispatch** event

This assumes a site with 2 store views, with following store codes

> es <- default
>
> en

**etc / frontend / events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="force_storecode_redirect" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ForceStorecodeRedirectObserver" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer / ForceStorecodeRedirectObserver.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ForceStorecodeRedirectObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $url;
    /** @var string $defaultStorecode */
    protected $defaultStorecode = 'es';
    /** @var array $storeCodes - array of existing storecodes*/
    protected $storeCodes = [];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
       $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
       $this->url = $url;
       $this->storeCodes = array_keys($this->storeManager->getStores(false, true));
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
         $urlParts = parse_url($this->url->getCurrentUrl());
         $path = $urlParts['path'];

         // get storecode from URL
         $urlCode = trim(substr($path, 0, 4), '/');

         // If path does not already contain an existing storecode
         if (!in_array($urlCode, $this->storeCodes)) {
             $path = ltrim($path, '/');
             if ($path == 'en') {
                 $path = '';
             }

             // Redirect to URL including storecode
             header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
             header("Location: " . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl() . $path);
             exit();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but also redirects admin uri. I changed line 32 to `if (!in_array($urlCode, $this->storeCodes) && strpos($path, 'admin') == false) {`

Answer (score 1):

You could to this through nginx:

```
## Redirect URLs without storecode to URLs with storecodes
set $storecode undefined;
if ( $http_host ~ ^(www\.)?ourproject.com ) {
    set $storecode en;
}

if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(skin|js|media|feeds|api|rest|index.php/admin|sitemaps)(|/$|/) ) {
    set $storecode reset;
}


if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(en)(|/$|/) ) {
    set $storecode reset;
}

if ( $storecode = en ) {
    rewrite ^(.*) http://$host/$storecode$1 permanent;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in Apache / htaccess?

Comment: For me this gives an error when accessing the Admin backend: `Requested store cannot be found`. It tries to receive a frontend storeview by the code `admin_custom` which obviously does not exist. Even if I add the `admin_custom` to the exeptions list in the second if-expression.

Comment: @Jacques you should add index.php/admin_custom to the exceptions behind sitemap with a pipe

Answer (score -2):

Simply go to backend Stores >> Configuration >> Web >> URL Options (set Add Store Code to Urls  to Yes.)
Clear cache and reindex.

Kudos if it works!

Comment: Using store codes is a requirement, if you read the question. Kind regards

Comment: Ya comment edited. Please check