# How to redirect default store view to en?

Tags: magento2, .htaccess, apache

I've got a store with 2 stores, one with 2 languages and the other just 1.

So:

> - Website > Store1 > English (www.site.com/en)
> - Website > Store1 >    French (www.site.com/fr)
> - Website > Store2 > English    (www.site2.com/eng)

The problem is that I've setup an in-house dev environment, and on this environment, I am able to go to www.site.com and www.site.com/en and it loads the same content, yet I can remove "use default" and actually show different content between the two store views.

Now I know the best way, would be to get rid of the English specific store_view and have that rely on the default (which is actually in the plan, but not scheduled for awhile).  But for now, I'd like to simply force all `www.site.com -> www.site.com/en/` when `/fr/` has not been explicitly chosen.

Does anybody know of an easy way to apply this in Apache2?

Comment: You should try this : > [Magento2 multistore - redirect url without store code to default
> storeView url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223505/magento2-multistore-redirect-url-without-store-code-to-default-storeview-url#answer-224898)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid doing it at the code level. I'd prefer to apply the change in Apache2 is possible.